# Why does ListView widget returns items as columns?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to achieve a simple layout, where the layout is a column of widgets the first item in the column is a text widget, and the second item is a row that contains multiple elevated buttons, this is my code it renders the elevated buttons one under each other instead of rendering it next to each other, so what I'm doing wrong here?

```dart
       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
       
       void main() => runApp(MyApp());
       
       class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
         final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
           {
             'question': "What's your favorite color?",
             'answers': ['Red', 'Blue', 'White', 'Black']
           },
           {
             'question': "What's your favorite animal?",
             'answers': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Lion', 'Monkey']
           }
         ];
       
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return MaterialApp(
             home: Scaffold(
               appBar: AppBar(
                 title: Text('Quiz'),
               ),
               body: Container(
                 height: double.maxFinite,
                 child: ListView.builder(
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     itemCount: questions.length,
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int questionsIndex) {
                       return Column(
                           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                           children: <Widget>[
                             SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                             Text(questions[questionsIndex]['question']),
                             SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                             ListView.builder(
                                 itemCount:
                                     questions[questionsIndex]['answers'].length,
                                 shrinkWrap: true,
                                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int answerIndex) {
                                   return Row(
                                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                     children: <Widget>[
                                       ElevatedButton(
                                         onPressed: null,
                                         child: Text(questions[questionsIndex]
                                             ['answers'][answerIndex]),
                                       ),
                                     ],
                                   );
                                 }),
                             SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                           ]);
                     }),
               ),
             ),
           );
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter `ListView` renders by default using the `Axis.Vertial`.

If you want the buttons to render next to each other that is horizontal axis, then you can set the scrollDirection propery of the ListView to `Axis.Hortizonal`.

If you must use a `ListView` then you'll need to `constrain` the height.

**Example:**

```dart
...
SizedBox(
 height: 64,
 child: ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection : Axis.horizontal,
...
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rohan thanks for your answer, I've already tried that but got this error `'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1865 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.
`

Comment: Wrap the list view with sizedbox and give height to it ~60 or increase the height based on your widgets in the listview

Comment: Updated my answer, to address the subsequent issue.